# Object location coordinates not using world origin as (0,0)

Tags: world

[image]
How do I set it back to world origin? My object is far from (0,0). I attach a screenshot.
Edit for clarification: my object is away from x0y0, yet the location of object is shown at y0, z0, x0.000002. For reference, the large sphere is 37.4m in diameter.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here without a screenshot etc., is the visible mesh of your object placed in the world's center but the location is shown as X/Y <> 0 (what about Z, this is 3D)? Or is the mesh out of the center and the coordinates as well so you just want to put it back? Or is the mesh out of the world's center but the coordinates are still showing X/Y = 0? Depending on what it is all these issues have different solutions...

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what you want but if you want to bring back your object tothe world center, press Alt G. Keep in mind that it's the origin of the object that will be taken into account, if you want to put the origin at the center of the mesh, right click in Object mode and Set Origin > To Geometry

Comment: @moonboots You forgot at least one more option: maybe it is _Set Origin_ > _Geometry to Origin_ what he wants. I could have listed all possible methods in my comment, but I would have actually liked him to ask a proper question which shows the issue, since as it stands this is a "low quality post".

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Yes you may be right

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I attached the screenshot. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @lexfriedman the formulation of the question is very poor. It is not clear what you want to do. "Set" can mean pretty much anything. Do you want to only set the origin to (0,0)?.. Do you want to move the geometry to the center?.. Who knows?.. You should edit the question and put some effort into communicating it better.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys edited again 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classical Blender/3D understanding.

In Blender, like in other softwares, any 3D Object has an **origin point**. It's the position of that origin point that you see on the properties panel :

[image: The default cube]

Blender displays the origin point as a little orange dot.

If I **move the cube in Object Mode**, the origin point will follow :

[image: moving in object mode]

But If **I move it in Edit Mode**, only the cube's vertices will move and the origin point will stay at the same location :

[image: moving in edit mode]

And after that if I swicth back to Object mode and check the object's location, this is what I would see :

[image: cube in object mode] [image: properties panel]

The orange dot is still at the 0 position hence the display in the properties panel.

In the screenshot you posted, the origin point of your object is near the center of the big sphere which is exactly at the position that Blender indicates. You can easily solve that by going to `Object` > `Set Origin` > `Origin to Geometry` :

[image: Origin to Geometry]

To sum it up, you need to **always pay attention in what mode you are in**. Operations done in Edit mode don't have the same effects as when you are doing them in Object Mode.

Comment: that's clear! so if I want to place another object in that exact place in space, I would have to bring it's origin to geometry and copy those coordinates? or is there another way?

Comment: Origin to Geometry will place your object's origin to the center of your object's mesh. Alternatively, if you chose Geometry to Origin, your Object's mesh will be moved to where the origin is. If you want to avoid doing that, always move your object in Object Mode unless you have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

I recreated your issue. The location of an object is the location of its origin (The orange dot which is usually in the centre of your object.)

Look in the image below. The orange dot, ie. the origin is still at the centre(x0,y0) but the actual geometry is actually away from the centre. This is not wrong in any way. It's just that you have probably moved the sphere while in the edit mode.

The origin point is used as the location and the pivot point for rotation. So in a few cases we actually need to modify the location of this origin for a specific purpose.

[image]

To bring back the geometry to the origin (like moving the geometry such that the mean position of the geometry is the location of your object origin) go  to Object (Or just right click on the model) > Set Origin > Geometry to origin.

[image]

Comment: wow, that is absolutely mad. how does it make sense? to me, it would make more sense if there were two sets of coordinates - one for object, the other for origin (my model spins around the origin, but has it's own location - that makes it less useful in current setup).

Comment: There is actually "two sets of coordinates" but not the way you would expect it. When you are in Object Mode, the numbers you see in the properties pannel are the position of the object i.e. the origin point but if you go to Edit Mode, the numbers will indicate the position of whatever you select (a set of vertices, edges or faces). So if you select all your vertices in Edit Mode, you would see the position of your mesh.